# After upgrade to Sphinx 7.0.1 Tables don't have colgroups assigned to them when I don't define widths in my .rst file

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am using sphinx to transform my rst files into jsons with html, and in my rst file I define
table without the widths like so:

```
list-table::
   :header-rows: 1
   
   * - Option A
     - Item B
     - Item C

   * - Option B
     - Item D
     - Item E
```

In the resulting html when we were using sphinx 4.3.1 we had a colgroup tag defining the widths of the table, to be of equal size. Now after upgrading to sphinx 7.0.1 we no longer have the colgroup tag appearing in the html structure and our tables are broken.
Why was this removed from sphinx? Was this default tables being of equal width functionality removed on purpose? I didn't find any mention of that in the changelog in the official sphinx site.
What would be the best approach to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by a change in Docutils 0.18. From the [release notes](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/RELEASE-NOTES.html#release-0-18-2021-10-26):

> Make "auto" table column widths the default: Only specify column widths, if the "widths" option is set and not "auto". The table-style setting "colwidths-grid" restores the current default.

To keep the old behaviour, add a [docutils.conf](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html) file in the [configuration directory](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/glossary.html#term-configuration-directory) of your Sphinx project, with the following content:

```
[html writers]
table-style: colwidths-grid
```

Comment: Thanks for the citation! I added the docutils.conf file with the tag mentioned by you, but it didn't have the effect I hoped for. The tables are still broken. I added it to the main folder where my rst files are located. In my documentation subfolders I have the conf.py files where I define some other properties like:

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
    'sphinxcontrib.fulltoc'
#    'rstjinja'
#    'sphinxnormalizeimages'
]
etc.
Maybe I could try to define this table property there?

Comment: docutils.conf should be in the same directory as conf.py (the configuration directory). https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html